# How would you write a @debuggable decorator in python?

Tags: python, decorator

When debugging, I like to print out all the inputs and outputs of a function (I know I need a better IDE, but humour me, this could be used for error reporting). So, I'd ideally like to have:

```
@debuggable
def myfunc(argA,argB,argC):
    return argB+1
```

and use a global variable to switch on or off debugging. No, you don't like globals either, I guessed.

The best I can come up with is:

```
DEBUG = True

def debuggable(func):
    if DEBUG:
        def decorated(*args):
            print "Entering ",func.func_name
            print "    args ",args
            ret = func(*args)
            print ret
            return ret
        return decorated
    else:
        return func

@debuggable
def myfunc(this,that):
    return this+that
```

And running:

```
>>> myfunc(1,3)
Entering  myfunc
   args  (1, 3)
4
```

How can I improve that?

Comment: There's a fairly long blog post on the subject of tracing decorators at [Word Aligned](http://wordaligned.org/articles/echo).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use a debugger. Seriously. Decorating every function you want to keep track is a bad idea.

Python [has a debugger included](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html), so you don't need a good IDE.

If you don't want to use a debugger, you can use the [trace function](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.settrace).

```
import sys

@sys.settrace
def trace_debug(frame, event, arg):
    if event == 'call':
        print ("calling %r on line %d, vars: %r" % 
                (frame.f_code.co_name, 
                 frame.f_lineno,
                 frame.f_locals))
        return trace_debug
    elif event == "return":
        print "returning", arg

def fun1(a, b):
    return a + b

print fun1(1, 2)
```

That prints:

```
calling 'fun1' on line 14, vars: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
returning 3
3
```

Even easier would be to use [Winpdb](http://winpdb.org/):

It is a **platform independent** graphical GPL Python debugger with support for remote debugging over a network, multiple threads, namespace modification, embedded debugging, encrypted communication and is up to 20 times faster than pdb.

Features:

- GPL license. Winpdb is Free Software.
- Compatible with CPython 2.3 or later.
- Compatible with wxPython 2.6 or later.
- Platform independent, and tested on Ubuntu Gutsy and Windows XP.
- User Interfaces: rpdb2 is console based, while winpdb requires wxPython 2.6 or later.

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [winpdb.org](http://winpdb.org/images/screenshot_winpdb_small.jpg))</sub>

Comment: While this is nice info, it is not really an answer to the question.

Answer (score 13):

I think what you're after isn't really a debugging decorator, but more of a logging decorator.

It might make sense to use [Python's logging module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) so you can have more fine grained control over the logging itself.  For example you would be able to output to a file for later analysing the output.

The decorator might then look something more like:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('TraceLog')
# TODO configure logger to write to file/stdout etc, it's level etc


def logthis(level):
    def _decorator(fn):
        def _decorated(*arg,**kwargs):
            logger.log(level, "calling '%s'(%r,%r)", fn.func_name, arg, kwargs)
            ret=fn(*arg,**kwargs)
            logger.log(level, "called '%s'(%r,%r) got return value: %r", fn.func_name, arg, kwargs, ret)
            return ret
        return _decorated
    return _decorator

@logthis(logging.INFO)
def myfunc(this,that):
    return this+that
```

Then if you configure the logger to output to stderr you'd see:

```
>>> logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
>>> handler=logging.StreamHandler()
>>> logger.addHandler(handler)
>>> myfunc(1,2)
calling 'myfunc'((1, 2),{})
called 'myfunc'((1, 2),{}) got return value: 3
```

Answer (score 11):

I agree with nosklo using a debugger is much better than writing your own. I'll post an improvement to your code. But I still think you should follow nosklo's advice.

Use decorator classes to make your debugger neater:

```
class Debugger(object):
    enabled = False
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.enabled:
            print 'Entering', self.func.func_name 
            print '    args:', args, kwargs
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

Debugger.enabled = True

@Debugger
def myfunc(a, b, c, d):
    pass
```

Comment: Nice.  I didn't know that classes could be used as decorators, but I guess it should have been obvious that it is possible.  ;p

Answer (score 2):

Here is my debug decorator.

```py
import sys
import time

level = 0

def debug(f):
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        global level
        sys.stderr.write("[debug] %s%s(%s)\n"
            % (' ' * level,
                f.__name__, ", ".join(
                    [str(a) for a in args]
                    + ["%s=%s" % (k, v) for (k, v) in kwargs.items()])))
        level += 1
        t0 = time.time()
        res = f(*args, **kwargs)
        t1 = time.time()
        level -= 1
        sys.stderr.write("[debug] %s= %r (%.9f s)\n"
            % (' ' * level, res, t1 - t0))
        return res
    return decorated
```

This is an improvement over Phil’s because :

- it uses stderr, hence preserving meaningful output on stdout,
- it improves visibility on recursive calls
- it measures the duration of the debugged function (not requested, but not a big hindrance either)

I use `f.__name__` instead of `f.func_name`, because the former doesn’t work anymore in python 3.8.

I took the hint from John Montgomery to not forget to treat kwargs.

I did not keep the DEBUG global variable, not because of its nature, but because I consider it simpler to put/remove a line with `@debug` where I want it debugged/cleaned. I won’t commit them, as I differentiate punctual manual debug to logging.

Small example

```py
@debug
def f(a, b):
    return a + b

@debug
def g(a, b, c):
    return f(a, b) * c

class C:
    @debug
    def m1(self, a, b):
        return a / b

    @classmethod
    @debug
    def m2(c, a, b):
        return b - a

    @staticmethod
    @debug
    def m3(a, b):
        return a * b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f(1, b=2)
    g(1, 2, 3)
    C().m1(3, 4)
    C.m2(5, 6)
    C.m3(7, 8)
```

Output

```
$./test.py >/dev/null
[debug] f(1, b=2)
[debug] = 3 (0.000001431 s)
[debug] g(1, 2, 3)
[debug]  f(1, 2)
[debug]  = 3 (0.000000477 s)
[debug] = 9 (0.000024557 s)
[debug] m1(<__main__.C object at 0x7f10a6465d90>, 3, 4)
[debug] = 0.75 (0.000000715 s)
[debug] m2(<class '__main__.C'>, 5, 6)
[debug] = 1 (0.000000477 s)
[debug] m3(7, 8)
[debug] = 56 (0.000000477 s)
```

I understand that a real debugger is a tool that should be known, but the simplicity of adding a small decorator in the editor should be taken in account. As with any tool, proper usage is defined by context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as decorator for debug; (@debug)

```
def debug(func):
    import functools

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_debug(*args, **kwargs):
        args_repr = [repr(a) for a in args]  # 1
        kwargs_repr = [f"{k}={v!r}" for k, v in kwargs.items()]  # 2
        signature = ", ".join(args_repr + kwargs_repr)  # 3
        print(f"Call {func.__name__}({signature})")
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(f"{func.__name__!r} return {value!r}")  # 4
        return value

    return wrapper_debug
```

Answer (score -1):

I second what nosklo said.

Another thing to notice is that your function is a bit dangerous:

```
b = myfunc(1,3)
```

In this case, "b" is `None`, because the decorated function doesn't return anything.