# How to execute a Nautilus script written in Python inside a gnome-terminal window that stays open?

Tags: python, shell, gnome-terminal, nautilus

Lets say I want to execute a simple Python script from *Nautilus*, the default file manager of *GNOME*:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
print("Hello")
```

Of course the aim is to interact with selected files in *Nautilus*, but I want to keep it simple.

I save the script to the folder `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/` and then I can execute it from the right click context menu:

[image: Nautilus script context menu]

How can I execute this [nautilus script](http://g-scripts.sourceforge.net/) inside *gnome-terminal* and keep the terminal opened at the end of the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that I can achieve what I want to do using two script files.

[image: Script folder]

**1) `Hello.sh` to open *gnome-terminal (and potentially leave it open)***

The first script file `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/Hello.sh` will appear in Nautilus script context menu and will open *gnome-terminal* in order to execute `.Hello.py`:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -- python3 ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/.Hello.py
```

To force the terminal window to stay open after execution (to see output or for debugging purpose if it fails), tweak it as follow to make *gnome-terminal* execute `bash` at the end:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "python3 ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/.Hello.py; bash"
```

**2) `.Hello.py` to execute the actual script**

Then, the second script file `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/.Hello.py` will be executed inside the *gnome-terminal* windows opened previously but will be hidden from nautilus script context menu.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
print("Hello")
```